# How to convert an image file of lines into a lines shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, georeferencing, raster-conversion

I need to convert the following image into a line .shp file. I can make the image into whatever type of image file it needs to be before converting. For context, I had started mapping an area by drawing over the map in photoshop but then came across QGIS and finished the project by mapping over the image using lines shapefile layers. I'm now trying to run the lines through a matlab code and the code can only use shapefiles.[image]

I haven't used QGIS extensively.

Comment: Whats the resolution of that image? Because most of the lines are barely a pixel or two wide, there's lots of intersections and junctions and places where several lines overlap and are indistinct - how precise do you need this? It might be easier to get the source in a vector format...